# Vue.js file bundle.js is connected only along the path '/'

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I started an express server using webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware. But for some reason the bundle.js file is connected only on the '/' route, but not on the '/page' route. It's as if HtmlWebpackPlugin refuses to connect the script along this route to the index.html file. I am attaching my code.

> app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const config = require('../webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('../public'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000!\n');
});
```

> webpack.config.js

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['./src/main.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      templateParameters: {
        BASE_URL: '/'
      },
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'), // Укажите путь к вашему файлу index.html
      title: 'Господи помоги', // Можно задать или использовать переменные
    }),
  ],
};
```

> vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: '/',
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

> main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

> router.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import Page from './components/Page.vue';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: HelloWorld
        },
        {
            path: '/page',
            component: Page
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import Page from './components/Page.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Page
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

> HelloWorld.vue (Page.vue is the same)

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
      Test paragraph
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

If I change publicPath: '/' in webpack.config.js to '/page', then the '/page' path starts working, but the '/' path stops.